# A bit tricky exercise that I'm currently looking for help to solve it

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH3KeH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The exercise:

> We switch 200 V as a resulting voltage on two capacitors in series. 
> The charge of the two capacitor is 10 µAs (Q1=Q2).
>
> What is the capacitance of the two, if C1 = 4C2 ?

The capacitative voltage divider would be an option, but we do not know either capacitance.

Comment: Hi Norbert! I don't understand this sentence: "We switch 200 V as a resulting voltage on two capacitors in series." who switches what, in what circuit? Did that exercise maybe come with context or a schematic that you're omitting here?

Comment: And, you say: "The capacitative voltage divider would be an option, but we do not know either capacitance." Sounds like you have an approach that works, in principle, up to the point where you have to insert values. How far did you get doing that? Please add your work to your question!

Comment: @Marcus Müller Hi Marcus! Sorry for the mislead, I meant that the generator voltage in the circuit is 200 V, and the two capacitors are in series.
We know the charge of them which is 10 µAs, and the exercise asking the value of the two capacitors if C1 = 4C2.

It would be a bit easier if a I can upload the draw of it, but it's an easy circuit built up by a voltage generator and two capacitors in series.
Thanks Marcus!

Comment: OK, I still don't understand that, but that sounds like you know how to draw that as a schematic. Please **edit** your question and include the schematic. You can use the built-in schematic editor, or export a picture from your favorite schematic capture software, or just draw it on paper and take a *sharp, and straight* photo of your drawing, and add it. There's nothing stopping you from that – as a new user, you can not directly *embed* pictures, but you can upload them and have the link.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks a lot, with schematic is far more easier, I uploaded the changes and the schematic.

Comment: What are \$\mu A s\$? micro-amp-seconds?

Comment: @Andyaka That's correct! The capacitor stored charge measure unit, which is basically Amp seconds.

Comment: @Norbert Kts I suggest rewording your question to "When 200V is applied across the 2 capacitors in series, they both attain 10uC charge each at steady state."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let X be the total capacitance, then

Q = U * X = 200V * X = 10 uC

X = 1/20 uC / V = 50 nF

This is the total capacitance of the two series caps. Now figure C2 in the task:

50nF = C2 * 4*C2 / (C2 + 4*C2) = 4*C2^2 / 5*C2 = 4/5 * C2

C2 = 5/4 * 50nF = 62.5nF

C1 = 4*C2 = 250nF

Comment: Very nice! Checking with the voltage divider it's correct, I mean U = U1+U2 = 40+160 V. 
So thanks for your solution!

Comment: The only thing that I can't really see, how is it that you wrote the voltage divider on the right side C2*4C2 / (C2+4C2) ?

Comment: No it's just the formula for series caps. C=1/(1/C1+1/C2) = C1*C2 / (C1+C2). And directly substituted 4*C2 for C1.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's not a voltage divider, you're right, thanks!

Comment: Actually it is a capacitive voltage divider. You can calculate with that just like with resistors, but don't forget that the reactance of caps is inversely proportional to the capacitance.

Comment: It's similar to it, but I think it's just the addition of the two capacitors, like if they would be two resistors in parallel, and we use the reciprocal.